# Stata - Preserving encoded variable and stacked graphing

Tags: graph, visualization, stata

These data represent ice cream preferences where individuals can change these preferences over time

```
id      time   flavor_str     flavor_enc  
 1       1         C               1
 1       2         C               1
 1       3         V               2
 2       1         S               3
 2       2         V               2
 2       3         C               1
 3       1         V               2
 4       1         C               1  
 4       2         V               2
```

Note: `flavor_enc` is showing a number, but in Stata it would show the string name in blue, which represents the number

Two issues.

When I create a variable off of the encoded, for example

```
g initial_pref = 0
replace initial_pref = flavor_enc if = time == 1
```

OR

```
bysort id: egen max_pref = max(flavor_enc)
```

The variable `first_pref` takes on the encoded numeric, however, I would like to keep it in the same format as `flavor_enc`.

I then want to create a stacked bar chart (by flavor on the x-axis) and the frequency (on the y-axis). The chart would have one piece of the bar that represents the number of times a given flavor was someones initial preference, a second piece that represents the number of times that flavor was someone's second preference (they switched from their initial, 0 otherwise), and the last piece representing the number of times a flavor was their third preference.

For these data the chart would use these inputs.

```
C as initial = 2
V as initial = 1
S as initial = 1

C as second = 0
V as second = 3
S as second = 0

C as third = 1
V as third = 0
S as third = 0
```

I tried `graph bar` with the stacking option but that did not work. I also could see how to do this outside of Stata but was hoping Stata had the functionality.

Comment: In your example data, are you aware that `C`, `S`, and `V` are all coded as `3` for `id ==2` ? Other inconsistencies are present. Are they intentional? You mention a variable `first_pref`, but you code `initial_pref`. Are these supposed to be the same?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Thank you, that was a typo. Fixed

Comment: The word "format" is heavily overloaded in computing and that's not your fault. But it's crucial that Stata's sense of display format is nothing at all to do with your question which seems to be about keeping value labels and the one-word answer is `clonevar`, as @RobertoFerrer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording is not completely clear to me, but I believe the first issue can be managed with `clonevar`:

```
clonevar initial_pref2 = flavor_enc
replace initial_pref2 = 0 if time != 1
```

Regarding your latest comment (and edit), if you want to compute the maximum and still use `clonevar`, it is possible:

```
clonevar max_pref2 = flavor_enc
bysort id (max_pref2): replace max_pref2 = max_pref2[_N]
```

If you have missings in `flavor_enc`, adjustments are necessary.

An alternative solution involves extracting the data attributes from the original variable using *extended macro functions* (`help extended_fcn`), and assigning them to the new variable.

One way to tackle the graph issue is as follows:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id      time   str1 flavor_str     flavor  
 1       1         C               1
 1       2         C               1
 1       3         V               2
  2       3         C               1
 2       1         S               3
 2       2         V               2
 3       1         V               2
 4       2         V               2
  4       1         C               1  
end

drop flavor_str

sort id time
list, sepby(id)

*----- bar graph -----

quietly tabulate time, gen(tt)
collapse (sum) tt*, by(flavor)

label define lblflavor 1 "flavor 1" 2 "flavor 2" 3 "flavor 3"
label values flavor lblflavor

graph bar (asis) tt*, over(flavor) stack ///
    ylabel(none) blabel(bar, position(center)) legend(off)
```

But for sure there is a better way. I seldom use these so my experience is minimal.

I can't say much about its appropriateness except that for this example, it seems like an awful waste of space.

Comment: This works only for some instances but not when something like max is used. It still returns the encoded number and not the format from the encoded variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "when something like max is used"? I see no `max()` in your example code. Furthermore, what do you mean by "... not the format from the encoded variable"? From `help clonevar`:  "clonevar generates newvar as an exact copy of an existing variable, varname, with the same storage type, values, and display format as varname.  varname's variable label, value labels, notes, and characteristics will also be copied."

Comment: I only put one example of creating a variable from the encoded, but wanted a more general solution

Comment: Then your original example is not representative enough; nor can we guess you are thinking of something more "general" unless you are explicit about it.  I consider `clonevar` a general solution: clone a variable and then put the desired values in it. I have also provided an alternative (with no example).